# ORA-03114 Getting a report

Tags: oracle, report, ora-03114

Do you know any reason to get the following error when I'm taking a few Oracle Reports?

"FRM-40735: ON-ERROR trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-03114"

This happens some times to a few users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE` is an error with several possible causes.  As it suggests, it means your client (Forms in this case) has been disconnected from the database.

It's possible that the database or the listener has shut down.  Or perhaps a problem with the client has caused the database to disconnect you.  There may well be some messages in the database alert log.

Answer (score 2):

`ORA-03114` is "Not Connected to Oracle" - i would begin by troubleshooting this issues first.

Answer (score 2):

Either you got disconnect in some way (perhaps an idle connection timeout)
or someone shut down the DB while you were connected. Either way, it means you are disconnected from the database.